# Разделить один массив на два

Tags: php, массивы, алгоритм, случайные-числа

Задача такая - есть массив который нужно разделить на два массива

Все элементы которые попадут в массивы должны быть случайные.

---

$list - Базовый массив

$red_team - первый массив

$blue_team - второй массив

---

Ниже приведен не рабочий код

```
$list = array("foo", "bar", "hallo", "world");
if (count($list) % 2 == 0)
{
    $rand_list = array_rand($list, count($list) / 2);
    for ($i = 0; $i <= count($rand_list); $i++)
    { 
        $red_team[] = $list[$rand_list[$i]];
        unset($list[$rand_list[$i]]);
        $blue_team = $list;
        unset ($list);
    }
}
```

На что сервер ответил так

```
NOTICE Undefined variable: list on line number 9

NOTICE Undefined variable: list on line number 10

NOTICE Undefined variable: list on line number 11

NOTICE Undefined offset: 2 on line number 9

NOTICE Undefined variable: list on line number 9

NOTICE Undefined offset: 2 on line number 10

NOTICE Undefined variable: list on line number 10

NOTICE Undefined variable: list on line number 11
```

Comment: А зачем вы делаете `unset ($list);`? Буквально на второй итерации цикла он, естественно, уже будет undefined

Comment: `shuffle($list);
list($red, $blue) = array_chunk($list, ceil(count($list)/2));`

Comment: @rjhdby `unset($list[$rand_list[$i]]);` удаляет случайный элемент массива а потом там остается лишние элементы которые я перевожу в $blue_team. Дальше я не вижу смысла в существования $list

Comment: @Мелкий очень интересный код в котором я ничего не понял ;0 . На исходе точно будет два массива $red и $blue

Comment: два массива из случайных элементов начального списка, нечёное число элементов даст +1 элемент в первой группе. Предусловие забыл, `count($list) >= 2`. На массиве из 1 элемента замечание будет всё-таки.

Comment: if (count($list) >= 2) shuffle($list); list($red, $blue) = array_chunk($list, ceil(count($list)/2)); endif;

Comment: @СашаАдамов у вас последним оператором цикла стоит `unset ($list);` - этот оператор на первой итерации уничтожает `$list` целиком. На следующей итерации, в строке `$red_team[] = $list[$rand_list[$i]];` вы пытаетесь использовать `null` как массив

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не вдаваясь в разбирательства с исходным кодом, задачу можно решить буквально в 2 строки:

```
shuffle($list);
list($red, $blue) = array_chunk($list, ceil(count($list)/2));
```

`shuffle` перемешает элементы массива случайным образом, `array_chunk` распилит на части указанной величины. `ceil` от половины массива даст в результате распиливание массива ровно пополам с переносом нечётного элемента в первый список.

Разбиение будет выполнено с ошибкой для списка из 0 или 1 элемента. Но это очевидно должно проверяться сильно раньше по логике приложения. Делить одного игрока на две команды (очевидно из наименований переменных) - штука странная.

---

Или простым флагом перекладывать в нужные массив

```
shuffle($list);
$red = $blue = [];
$isOdd = true;
foreach ($list as $el) {
    if ($isOdd) {
        $red[] = $el;
    } else {
        $blue[] = $el;
    }
    $isOdd = !$isOdd;
}
```

---

Или взять пару `array_slice`

```
shuffle($list);
$slice = floor(count($list)/2); // можно ceil, разница только на нечётном объёме $list
$red = array_slice($list, 0, $slice);
$blue = array_slice($list, $slice);
```

Вторые два варианта корректно обрабатывают и пустые списки тоже.

В общем, `shuffle` для не криптостойкого перемешивания более чем достаточно, а распилить затем неупорядоченный массив на две части можно разными способами.

Comment: а чего нить там типа `$teams[$isOdd = !$isOdd][] = $el` не прокатит? или там какое нить `$teams[$k%2][] = $el`

Comment: @teran всё возможно. Способов нарезать один массив на части много можно придумать.

Answer (score 1):

Это исправление вашего кода. В таком виде оно работает.

```
$list = array("foo", "bar", "hello", "world");
if (count($list) % 2 == 0)
{
    $rand_list = array_rand($list, count($list) / 2);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($rand_list); $i++)
    { 
        $red_team[] = $list[$rand_list[$i]];
        unset($list[$rand_list[$i]]);
    }
    $blue_team = array_values($list);
    unset ($list);
}
```

Сами исправления:

- В php принято считать от "0", и в циклах проверку пишут "i < count", а не "i <= count"
- Присвоение $blue_team ошибочно попало в цикл.
- Если не использовать метод array_values, то ключи в массиве $blue_team будут идти вразнобой (что может быть и не критичным)

Comment: Thanks 
Я вот думаю. Мне дали еще один очень интересный ответ но даже не знаю который выбирать

Comment: @Саша Адамов очевидно же, что ответ господина *Мелкий* является идеальным решением )

Comment: @Эдуард если б он дал это как не коментарий а как ответ